# Infragistics Pivot Grid vs DevExpress Pivot Grid

Tags: devexpress, pivot-table, infragistics

I'm working on a Winforms product that merges both control libraries, and I'd like to see it consolidated into one or the other. The application uses Infragistics more heavily than DevExpress so that seems to be the likely candidate, but Pivot Grid functionality utilizes DevExpress making it a big hurdle to jump in convincing others involved to switch over to Infragistics. My question is how they compare. I'm fairly new to both Libraries, and instead of simply comparing documentation and features, I'm hoping to know if anyone has experience in switching from one control to the other, and what "gotchas" might be in store if such a move is made. Also, which is more powerful, and how so? This will help give me some expertise credit that I can use to create an argument one way or another. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You really need to evaluate which better meets your specific needs on your own.  Other people may not need the same features as you and relying on their experience may give you the wrong answer for your own scenario.

Comment: I'm not asking for anyone to make my decision, I'm asking for more informed opinions about the differences between the two. That should be pretty obvious.